# Derivative of eigenvalue with respect to a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having trouble wrapping my mind against a simple problem: Suppose we have the following eigenvector equation for $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$
\left(\alpha A\right)u = \lambda u
$$

Where $u$ is an eigenvector for $A$ and $\lambda$ is its eigenvalue.

I am trying to compute
$$
\frac{d\lambda}{d\alpha }
$$

Since, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then $\alpha \lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $\alpha A$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. It follows that

$$
\lambda = \alpha c_0; \ c_0\in \mathbb{C}
$$

Rearranging terms and letting $c_1 = \log c_0$, we have that

$$
\log\lambda = \log \alpha + c_1
$$

Which can be written as

$$
\int \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda} = \int \frac{d\alpha}{\alpha} + c_1
$$

From this last equation, is it logical to conclude, therefore, that

$$
\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda} = \frac{d\alpha}{\alpha}
$$

and hence,

$$
\frac{d\lambda}{d\alpha} = \frac{\lambda}{\alpha} \ ?
$$

I have never solved an equation of this form. What I did realize is that is that, solving this equation was the *inverse* of solving an ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lambda(\alpha)=\alpha\lambda(1)\implies\frac{d\lambda(\alpha)}{d\alpha}=\lambda(1).$$

Comment: You are making this ten times more complicated than necessary.